# City' object has no attribute 'region__name' in django-autocomplete-light

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an searchable dropdown which fetch data directly from the tables(models).

and this is City table:

[image]

and as you see it's trying to join `country` and `region` tables as well.
and in view I have this:

```
class LocationAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return City.objects.none()

        qs = City.objects.all().select_related('country', 'region')


        if self.q:

            qs = qs.select_related('country', 'region').filter(name__icontains=self.q)
        return qs

    def get_result_label(self, item):
        return format_html('<b>{}</b>-{}-{}', item.name, item.region__name, item.country__name)
```

That in above, `item.name` return all names in city table, but region__name or item.country__name are not defined. To me it means `select_related` is not joining them like SQL queries.

Based on the definition of select_related:

> Select all related data when executing the query (except many-to-many
> relationships)

But I get this error( which means region__name is not selected at the end!):

```
'City' object has no attribute 'region__name'
```

In shell I just tried with `values()` as follows:

```
qs = City.objects.all().select_related('country', 'region').values('id', 'name', 'country__name', 'region__name')
```

it returns a list of dictionaries with all mentioned attributes in `values()` however I get the error in view when I replace it:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the region name you are writing underscore instead of a dot to follow the relationship.
Just change the line by:

```
    def get_result_label(self, item):
        return format_html('<b>{}</b>-{}-{}', item.name, item.region.name, item.country.name)
```